# PHPUnit will not run after virtual box, php and vagrant upgrades

Tags: php, phpunit

I took this morning to upgrade some libraries I use for work. My Mac OSX is now using PHP 7.1 and also upgraded my virtual box to 5.1 and vagrant to 1.9.1. My single-project is also using PHP 7.1.2 and I am using PHPUnit 6.0 for the project.

Everything seems to be working fine except PHPUnit. When I run:

```
bash vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I get the following output:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit:2: no such file or directory: ?php
vendor/bin/phpunit:3: permission denied: /Applications
vendor/bin/phpunit:4: command not found: Homestead.yaml
vendor/bin/phpunit:5: command not found: Homestead.yaml
vendor/bin/phpunit:7: parse error near `\n'
```

Looked on Google and couldn't find anything and have hit a brick wall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmmm
why

`bash vendor/bin/phpunit` ?

IMHO should be  `php vendor/bin/phpunit`

phpunit  is a php script

Comment: Jesus... This has been bugging me for hours. What a stupid mistake! At the top of the phpunit file it has a bash line so assumed it was a bash script then loading PHP through it or something.